# Gaussian Blur Overlay (iOs/osTV style) Effect with Indesign CS6?

Tags: adobe-indesign, cs6, creative-cloud, ios, overlay

i'm looking for a way to perform this effect with inDesign but without Photoshop. Does anybody know how?
I tried many option but seem there is no way.
The only think maybe can work is the "insert HTML" object option.
Anybody know how to do it?
Thanks in advantage!

Comment: Are you talking about the ios quick settings?

Comment: There is actually quite a bit of tricks you can do with the Indesign Effects panel, most not obvious at all. I think there is a video on youtube that explores in turn how all the Indd effects can be exploited. Try searching for it.